# Mongoose - Objeto único em um array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

sou novo com MongoDB e Mongoose, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.

Gostaria de armazenar vários objetos em um array, sendo que o objeto deve ser único SOMENTE naquele array, baseado em uma string. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
var list = {
  name: "List 1",
  recipients: [
    // esse e-mail deve ser único NESSE array, mas, caso eu crie outro objeto 'list', ele pode ser adicionado novamente...
    {
      email: "email1@exemple.com"
    },
    {
      email: "email2@exemple.com"
    }
  ]
}

var list2 = {
  name: "List 2",
  recipients: [
    // essa é uma nova lista, vejam que posso adicionar o email2@exemple.com nessa nova lista
    {
      email: "email2@exemple.com"
    },
    {
      email: "email3@exemple.com"
    }
  ]
}

var list3 = {
  name: "List 3",
  recipients: [
    // já isso eu não quero que aconteça, vejam que existe 2 email2@exemple.com, isso eu NÃO quero...
    {
      email: "email2@exemple.com"
    },
    {
      email: "email2@exemple.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Vejam como está meu Schema:

```
var ListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  recipients: [
    {
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O índice `unique` evita duplicidade de *documentos* na coleção, não itens no array.

Utilize o operador [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/#op._S_addToSet) para adicionar um valor a um Array apenas se o valor não estiver presente.

```
var where = {_id: listId};
var update = {$addToSet: {recipients: userObj}};
List.update(where, update, function(err, numAffected) { ... });
```

No entanto, se você quer garantir unicidade em apenas um campo do objeto, e não no objeto inteiro, faça assim:

```
var where = {_id: listId, 'recipients.email': {$ne: userObj.email}};
var update = {$push: {recipients: userObj}};
List.update(where, update, function(err, numAffected) { ... });
```

Comment: Obg, vou tentar usar isso.